# AngularJS and AWS API Gateway API key not being sent

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, cors, aws-api-gateway

I've been struggling with making calls to my AWS API from my Angular/Ionic 1 Application.

I have an API proxy setup, and I've created an API key. I've configured the CORS in AWS, and everything works in postman fine, but when I make a request from my Angular App I get 403 {"message":"Forbidden"}.

This is the code I'm using to make the call:

```js
  getTodaysLiveGames:  function () {
    return $http({
        url: 'https://**************.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/livescores',
        headers: { 'x-api-key': '**************************************' },
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(function(result){
      ...
    }).catch(function(err){
      ...
    });
  },
```

In my AWS logs I'm getting the following:

> API Key not authorized because method 'OPTIONS /livescores' requires API Key and API Key is not associated with a Usage Plan for API Stage *******/prod: API Key was required but not present

I can't get my head around what the problem is. I setup an API key in AWS, attached it to a usage plan, and I've published it all correctly to the stage.

Can anyone help?

Comment: you need to add in th AWS allow options method.

Comment: Review [Enabling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ManageCorsUsing.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure 'X-Api-Key' is part of the mapping value for the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header in **/livescores** > **OPTIONS** > **Integration Response** > **Header Mappings**.